# Who is debian-tor in my /etc/passwd file?

Tags: 18.04, users, passwd-file

I have found this entry in `/etc/passwd`:

```
debian-tor:x:117:123::/var/lib/tor:/bin/false
```

But there is no `/var/lib/tor` folder. This is on a server not a desktop.

Comment: This is a user you created by installing something. Most likely you installed `tor`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a user that is created by installing `tor` or `tor-browser`.

For instance, if you look into `postinst` script of `tor` package, you'll see:

```
# checking debian-tor account

uid=`getent passwd debian-tor | cut -d ":" -f 3`
home=`getent passwd debian-tor | cut -d ":" -f 6`

# if there is the uid the account is there and we can do
# the sanit(ar)y checks otherwise we can safely create it.

if [ "$uid" ]; then
    if [ "$home" = "/var/lib/tor" ]; then
        :
        #echo "debian-tor homedir check: ok"
    else
        echo "ERROR: debian-tor account has an unexpected home directory!"
        echo "It should be '/var/lib/tor', but it is '$home'."
        echo "Removing the debian-tor user might fix this, but the question"
        echo "remains how you got into this mess to begin with."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    adduser --quiet \
        --system \
        --disabled-password \
        --home /var/lib/tor \
        --no-create-home \
        --shell /bin/false \
        --group \
        debian-tor
fi


for i in lib log; do
    if ! [ -d "/var/$i/tor" ]; then
        echo "Something or somebody made /var/$i/tor disappear."
        echo "Creating one for you again."
        mkdir "/var/$i/tor"
    fi
done

which restorecon >/dev/null 2>&1 && restorecon /var/lib/tor
chown debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor
chmod 02700 /var/lib/tor

which restorecon >/dev/null 2>&1 && restorecon /var/log/tor
chown debian-tor:adm /var/log/tor
chmod 02750 /var/log/tor
```

But this user is not removed when you uninstall `tor`. I don't see anything that removes the user in `prerm`, or `postrm` script.

So it means that you have `tor` installed, or installed it previously.

There is no harm in having some extra user in your system, but you can remove it if you like.

You can remove the user by running

```
sudo deluser debian-tor
```

Comment: that's exactly why I have asked. I have not nor would I ever install tor on a web server. So my follow-up question is how would i see the post-installation file that you are referencing in your answer and how to I remove the user and purge my system? If I run tor -v it is not installed.
also, there is no /var/lib/tor directory.

Comment: I added howto remove the user from your system. The postinst file is located in `tor` deb. Most likely someone installed `tor` and then removed it. I can't guess more.

Comment: thanks. interesting response afterward - Removing user `debian-tor' ...
Warning: group `debian-tor' has no more members.
Done.

Comment: So you can remove the group too. Nothing remarkable. The group had only one user.

Comment: groupdel: group 'debian-tor' does not exist
it just all seems very fishy

Comment: Most likely the group was automatically deleted when you deleted the only user from it.

Comment: @Pilot6 As for me, some authoritative link is needed. Like [this](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=getent+passwd+debian-tor&literal=1).

Comment: @N0rbert Anyone can download `tor` from Ubuntu repos and look into postinst script.